# Slick-pg: How to use arrayElementsText and overlap operator "?|"?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, slick-pg

I'm trying to write the following query in **scala** using *slick*/*slick-pg*, but I don't have much experience with slick and can't figure out how:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM attributes a 
WHERE a.other_id = 10 
      and ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(a.value->'value'))
          && array['1','30','205'];
```

This is a simplified version of the *attributes* table, where the *value* field is a **jsonb**:

```scala
class Attributes(tag: Tag) extends Table[Attribute](tag, "ship_attributes") {
    def id = column[Int]("id")
    def other_id = column[Int]("other_id")
    def value = column[Json]("value")

    def * = (id, other_id, value) <> (Attribute.tupled, Attribute.unapply)
```

}

Sample data:

```
|  id  |  other_id  |  value                                    |
|:-----|:-----------|:------------------------------------------|
|  1   |  10        | {"type": "IdList", "value": [1, 21]}      | 
|  2   |  10        | {"type": "IdList", "value": [5, 30]}      | 
|  3   |  10        | {"type": "IdList", "value": [7, 36]}      |
```

This is my current query:

```scala
attributes
    .filter(_.other_id = 10)
    .filter { a => 
        val innerQuery = attributes.map { _ => 
            a.+>"value".arrayElementsText
        }.to[List]
        innerQuery @& List("1", "30", "205").bind
    }
```

But it's complaining about the `.to[List]` conversion.

I've tried to create a `SimpleFunction.unary[X, List[String]]("ARRAY")`, but I don't know how to pass `innerQuery` to it (`innerQuery` is `Query[Rep[String], String, Seq]`).

Any ideas are very much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

while I can't figure this out, I changed the app to save in the database the json field as a list of strings instead of integer to be able to do this simple query:

```scala
attributes
    .filter(_.other_id = 10)
    .filter(_.+>"value" ?| List("1", "30", "205").bind)


|  id  |  other_id  |  value                                    |
|:-----|:-----------|:------------------------------------------|
|  1   |  10        | {"type": "IdList", "value": ["1", "21"]}  | 
|  2   |  10        | {"type": "IdList", "value": ["5", "30"]}  | 
|  3   |  10        | {"type": "IdList", "value": ["7", "36"]}  |
```

Comment: Well, the function equivalent of the `?|` operator is `jsonb_exists_any(jsonb,text[])` and the one for `&&` is `arrayoverlap(anyarray,anyarray)`, but that's as far as I can help you with rewriting the query. I don't know scala or that library to give a full answer. You can find these and other equivalent functions using `\do+ ?|` in the psql console for example.